# Akka Actors and Message Handling

Tags: java, akka

I have an ActorSystem where I create one top level actor and in this top level actor, I create a couple of child actors. So far good!

What I then do is to expose these child actors to my Application controller (in a Play application) so that I can directly pipe the messages intended for the corresponding child actor from my Play controller. Is this a good practice or should I always pipe the messages to the child actor via the supervisor? In code, it would look like below:

```
class Application extends Controller with MyActors {

  def createUser = { request =>
    val user: User = ... get the User from the request body
    userActor ! user
  }
}
```

Here is what my Supervisor Actor looks like and it is controlled by the Play applications lifecycle plugin:

```
class SupervisorActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  val allActors = MyActors(context.system.settings.config, context)

  context watch allActors.userActor

  // TODO: what should we do in this SupervisorActor?
  def receive = {
    case Terminated(terminate) => context stop self
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

I then inject this MyActors into the Play Application controller. So my question, is this a good approach? The child actors are receiving messages directly from the outside world, without the messages having to go through the Supervisor actor. Is this a good approach. What problems could I face with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing inherently bad or good about your approach.  Some problems call for direct communication with the child Actors and some call for using the supervisor.

I would say instances where contacting the supervisor is beneficial is if you need some type of routing logic, e.g. 1 message gets broadcasted to all child Actors or routing based on the contents of the message.

On the other hand it may be better to directly contact the children if the supervisor has other responsibilities and you want to distribute the work load.

I personally tend to communicate only with supervisors since it allows for a "single door" approach.  It is also usually easier to dependency inject the supervisor in other areas of the code, that way you don't have to go looking up the child ActorRef.

Comment: I do not have to do any look up on the child Actor as I created named references that I know in my Controller as to which child actor I'm sending the messages to! It is pretty straight forward. My child Actors act like a facade to my services which contain the business logic!

Comment: This is the "single door" I was talking about.

Comment: You mean, my child actors are like the single door? But it is a lot better than having one global supervisor actor to route requests to different child actors. Depending on the REST end-point, I know which actor to pass the message to in my controller! It is just like the fron facade design pattern!

Comment: The single point of contact, e.g. the HashMap with name --> ActorRef is the single door in this example.  As my answer stated, there is nothing inherently bad or good about either approach.  If you found a solution that works in your context, nobody would come along and claim that it is not idiomatic akka/scala.

Comment: Thanks for that, but what I wanted to know is that if there could be any potential pitfalls with this approach? Would routing the messages via the Supervisor buy me any advantage in case of any child actor failures? Is there anything that I might loose by circumventing message routing via the Supervisor?

Comment: There's no prima facie disadvantages to your approach.

Comment: That bolsters me on my approach. I will find out over the course of the project if this architecture holds good!